# JavaScript Object not loaded from through android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to load a .js file (WebViewJavascriptBridge.js) through webview of android. I placed the .js file in raw folder and tried to load it.
The .js file is in the below link.
https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster-client-android/blob/master/socketclusterandroidclient/src/main/assets/webviewjavascriptbridge.js

I used the following code to load the .js file.

```
InputStream is=mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.webviewjavascriptbridge);
String script=convertStreamToString(is)  
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+script);
```

when the above code is executed it prints in the locat:

09-08 11:43:28.195: D/WebViewJavascriptBridge---(27080): Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement line:2

Please correct me if am doing any wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is referring to the following code fragment:

```
if (window.WebViewJavascriptBridge3) {
    return;
}
```

This fragment contains a `return` statement outside of a function. This is not allowed by ECMAScript standard, and recent versions of V8 started to reject such code. Perhaps, you should just replace your `return` statement with a `throw`.

Now, the next question is why this return statement is hit -- because there is no `WebViewJavascriptBridge3` injected into your page. Can you please show the code that configures WebView, injects the object and loads the page? Note that all injected Java objects only become visible on the next load after calling `addJavascriptObject` function.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change to the script and it worked fine.

```
(function()
{
if (window.WebViewJavascriptBridge3) {
    return;
}


var messageHandlers = {};
var responseCallbacks = {};
var uniqueId = 1;

function init(messageHandler) {
    if (WebViewJavascriptBridge3._messageHandler) {
        throw new Error('WebViewJavascriptBridge3.init called twice');
    }
    WebViewJavascriptBridge3._messageHandler = messageHandler;
}

function _doSend(message, responseCallback) {
    console.log("responseCallback:" + responseCallback);
    if (responseCallback) {
        var callbackId = 'cb_' + (uniqueId++) + '_' + new Date().getTime();
        responseCallbacks[callbackId] = responseCallback;
        message['callbackId'] = callbackId;
    }
    console.log("sending:" + JSON.stringify(message));
    _WebViewJavascriptBridge._handleMessageFromJs(message.data || null, message.responseId || null,
        message.responseData || null, message.callbackId || null, message.handlerName || null);

}

function send(data, responseCallback) {
    _doSend({data: data}, responseCallback);
}

function registerHandler(handlerName, handler) {
    messageHandlers[handlerName] = handler;
}

function callHandler(handlerName, data, responseCallback) {
    _doSend({handlerName: handlerName, data: data}, responseCallback);
}



function _dispatchMessageFromJava(messageJSON) {
    var message = JSON.parse(messageJSON);
    var messageHandler;

    if (message.responseId) {
        var responseCallback = responseCallbacks[message.responseId];
        if (!responseCallback) {
            return;
        }
        responseCallback(message.responseData);
        delete responseCallbacks[message.responseId];
    }
    else {
        var responseCallback;
        if (message.callbackId) {
            var callbackResponseId = message.callbackId;
            responseCallback = function(responseData) {
                _doSend({
                    responseId: callbackResponseId,
                    responseData: responseData
                });
            };
        }

        var handler = WebViewJavascriptBridge3._messageHandler;
        if (message.handlerName) {
            handler = messageHandlers[message.handlerName];
        }
        try {
            handler(message.data, responseCallback);
        } catch(exception) {
            if (typeof console !='undefined') {
                console.log("WebViewJavascriptBridge3: WARNING: javascript handler threw.", message, exception);
            }
        }
    }
}

function _handleMessageFromJava(messageJSON) {
    _dispatchMessageFromJava(messageJSON);
}
window.WebViewJavascriptBridge3 = {
    'init': init,
    'send': send,
    'registerHandler': registerHandler,
    'callHandler': callHandler,
    '_handleMessageFromJava': _handleMessageFromJava
}})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Becompare to the original code, you lose the below code, how it run correctly?

```
//dispatch event
var doc = document;
var readyEvent = doc.createEvent('Events');
readyEvent.initEvent('WebViewJavascriptBridgeReady');
readyEvent.bridge = WebViewJavascriptBridge;
doc.dispatchEvent(readyEvent);
```